# My lucky number

Tags: number-theory, square-numbers

I don't know should I ask in Puzzling or not. Sorry for that if I'm wrong! And my question is, I have a lucky number that has four digits which the first three numbers and the last three numbers are perfect square and my lucky number's digits are different. I found the number but I couldn't figure out a mathematical way to solve. Appreciate your help!

Comment: What is the problem? A number as $169324$ is good?

Comment: The answer is not unique. (e.g. 289361 and 289576) If you know some program language, you can find possible answers by brute force.

Comment: @EmilioNovati I forgot to mention it is four digits

Comment: @HanulJeon I know I got help from Python but I wanted to do with a scientific way. And also look at my edit. The number is 4 digits

Comment: So $4981$ is good? You can test other possible solution by brute force.

Comment: @EmilioNovati.  496 and 964 are not perfect squares.  Also the digits must be different.

Comment: Sorry! now I understand the problem.

Comment: By an inspection it seems that the only solution is $7841$: $784=28^2$ and $841=29^2$.

Comment: $1441$ would make it and so would $7841$

Comment: @Shail, it says the digits are different. That rules out 1441.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is the number $7841$ since : $784=28^2$ and $841=29^2$.

An inspection to  a table of squares shows that this is the only possible solution.

Comment: OK, but I really wanted to find a way. Whatever, maybe there is not

Comment: Not an answer. The OP require that the digits of the number are different.